# SQL error - CodeIgniter login error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication

I'm trying to create a login function while learning CodeIgniter. I've validated that both the username and password are correct. The passwords are encrypted using Phppass codeigniter password library.

This is the error I get after I login with the correct information.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near

```
'(`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`)
 VALUES ('826f937fed9' at line 1

 INSERT INTO (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`,
 `last_activity`) VALUES ('826f937fed9185e2c121ec06b1b44b6a', '::1',
 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/53', 1442454002)
```

> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 327

Comment: [`INSERT ... [INTO] tbl_name ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) It's staring you right in the face.

Comment: I think the problem can be of " ' ". Replace "` `session_id` `" with " 'session' " and try. i.e. with quotes

Answer (score 0):

As Jarred Farrish and Darack on the PHP chatrooms pointed out the error was right in front of me! I had forgotten to add my CodeIgniter database tbl name to the config! Well, not exactly. I thought I followed the instructions from the CodeIgniter config correctly but apparently not! As the documentation differs slightly, you must in fact ADD

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

To your config.php file. Once that has been added CodeIgniter will correctly store user data in that table name provided.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** The Session class has built-in garbage collection which clears out expired sessions so you do not need to write your own routine to do it.

### It means you no need to insert it Manually. It will execute automatically.

---

In `config/config.php` change this

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
```

to this

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
```

---

and session table should be

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

---

check Session table name is

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```